# How to set tomcat.runtime.environment.version on the web server?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, environment

I have Java function:

```
public String getEnvironment(){
    String env =  System.getProperty("tomcat.runtime.environment.version");
    if(env == null)
        return "DEV";
    return  env;
}
```

and it is usually called this way:

```
string devEmail = configuration.getString(getEnvironment() + ".DEVELOPER_EMAIL");
```

Basically, getEnvironment will return strings (depending of environment) DEV, TEST or PROD and it will read from some configuration object proper information for current environment.

The part I don't understand is how is this set? How production server knows to return PROD, developemnt DEV, or test server to return TEST? Or, how do I set property "tomcat.runtime.environment.version" on the web server?

It's Apache Tomcat 6.0 web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add it to catalina.sh on linux or catalina.bat on windows.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dtomcat.runtime.environment.version=PROD"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Java System Property.  It can be set at JVM launch time with the "define" or `-D` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the property by adding it to CATALINA_OPTS environment variable:

`CATALINA_OPTS=-Dtomcat.runtime.environment.version=PROD`